# Are $f(x,y,z)=x$ and $f(x)=x$ equivalent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, notation

Suppose I have a function $f(x,y,z)=x$, is it equivalent to $f(x)=x$? Is it a correct abbreviation?

Or can I maybe write $g(x)=f(x,y,z)$ so $g(x)=x$?

What is mathematically correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Functions are mathematical objects which come along with a domain where they are defined (often we omit it making an harmless abuse of notation). Well, not so harmless given your question. The point is that only because the rule "assign the number $x$" is the same in both cases you can't say they are the same function (you haven't specified the domains, and even if you did there is no way they can match since one of them would be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the other a subset of $\mathbb{R}$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, this is not correct. Although you're capturing all the values of $f$ by just looking at the $x$ component, a function comes equipped with three pieces of data: first, the domain $D$ (in this case I assume you mean the domain of $f$ to be $\Bbb R^3$), the codomain $C$ (most likely $\Bbb R$, at least if my domain assumption is correct), and the rule itself (here $(x,y,z)\mapsto x$, more generally a subset $G\subseteq D\times C$ such that if $(d,c), (d,c')\in G$, then $c = c'$ and such that for every $d\in D$, there exists $c\in C$ such that $(d,c)\in G$). These three pieces of data are important to take into consideration when determining properties of $f$: two functions given by the same rule but with different domains/codomains might fail to have the same properties. You could define $g(x) = f(x,y_0,z_0)$ (for any choice of $y_0,z_0\in\Bbb R$), but then you have a function $g : \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ which is now surjective and injective, whereas $f$ was surjective but far from injective.

In fancier language, you might capture your idea by saying the value of $f$ only depends on the first coordinate of $\alpha\in\Bbb R^3$, and so $f : \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ descends to a function $\tilde{f} : X\to\Bbb R$ on the quotient space $X = \Bbb R^3/\sim$, where $(x,y,z)\sim (x',y',z')$ if $x = x'$, and this $X$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$.